# Ext js Model validation is throwing Error

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to validate my model using record.getValidation()  `Uncaught TypeError: factory is not a function(…)`

Below is my code and Ext js verison is 6.0.2

```
Ext.define('Student', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'Id',
    fields: [{
            name: 'Id',
            type: 'int'
        },
        'firstName',
        'lastName'
    ],
    validators: {
        firstName: 'presence',
        lastName: {
            type: 'length',
            min: 2
        }
    }

});
var studentRecord = Ext.create('Student', {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: 'J'
});

var validation = studentRecord.getValidation();
```

the above line is causing error getting factory is not a function. Kindly help me .

Comment: Look like a similar problem here at sencha  but no answer. https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303796-Ext-Factory-viewModel-is-not-a-function

Comment: [The issue does not occur if I put your code into fiddle.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1l31) Could you please provide a reproducible example in a fiddle?

Comment: UDID as you suggested I have tried by building testing environment it is working fine.. how can i accept your answer?